# How to set Default JTA data source JNDI name using jython WSadmin

Tags: linux, websphere, jython

I am trying to set Default JTA data source JNDI name using jython WSadmin.

try with the following command.

```
 AdminTask.setDefaultManagedExecutor('[-server server1 -targetJndiName jdbc/wemDST]')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cellName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(AdminConfig.list("Cell"), "name")
newDSName = "jdbc/whatever"
AdminTask.setDefaultDataSource('/Cell:' + cellName + '/', '[-targetJndiName ' + newDSName + ']')
AdminConfig.save()
```